# Seeking Automated Text Wrapping Around Figures in LaTeX: struggling with wrapfig

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, text, wrapfig

I would like to have **figures with automatic text wrapping around them**. I am trying to keep having to tweak figure locations to minimum. I am also not allowed to use two columns for this document.

[image: What I want]

What I have already tried: Here is a Minimal Working Example (MWE) that I tried to use. In the MWE, changing the variable \wrapenvironment switches between different wrapping environments like `\wrapfig`, `\wrapstuff`, and `\floatflt`, all of them produce outputs where there are massive blank spaces that could have been filled with text. What should I assign as the value for `\wrapenvironment` that will give me an output (**automatic text wrapping without huge white spaces**) similar to the example above?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small} 
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry} % Set 0.5-inch margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for custom headers and footers
\usepackage{lipsum} % For sample text

\usepackage{wrapstuff} % For wrapping text around figures
\usepackage[vflt]{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\def\wrapenvironment{wrapstuff}

\title{MWE Figure Wrapping fails}
\date{January 2024}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{\wrapenvironment} %{L}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{\wrapenvironment}

\lipsum[11-14]

\begin{\wrapenvironment} %{L}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{\wrapenvironment}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{\wrapenvironment} %{L}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image}    
\end{\wrapenvironment}

\lipsum[15-20]


\end{document}
```

Comment: These are several problems and therefore you should ask questions for each of them including MWEs to make them reproducible. If you only search for alternatives to `wrapfig` see, e.g.,  https://ctan.org/topic/text-flow

Comment: The package `wrapstuff ` is a possible alternative. A more efficient use of space, please define the term is to have the figures in the margins. So as @cabohah suggested please give some more details about your document.

Comment: A viable alternative is not to use wrapfig at all,  but a two column layout or a tufte class like [here](https://ctan.fisiquimicamente.com/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-handout.pdf). This does not allow you to make L-shaped paragraphs, but I don't see much fun on this, sincerely.

Comment: Wrapfig is based on `\parshape` which is line rather than space) oreiented.  Wrapfig automatically assumes the lines are spaced `\baselineskip` apart.  When that isn't true, you need to count the number of lines needed.  You can use paracol instead, but you will have to manually break the text going in and/or out.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620345/indentation-problem-with-wrapfigure-and-listings/620404?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C34.8836#620404 for example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 

@yannisl wrapstuff seems great, but does not respect margin sizes. 
@DavidCarlisle I am already using  wrapfig's ```L``` and ```R```, but then I get huge white spaces next to the first figure when there are two in a row. 
@Fran I love the idea of using two column layout, but I am not allowed to for this document.
@JohnKormylo this seems like quite a bit of manual tweaking?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have updated the minimum working example using ```example-image```.

Comment: thanks, I removed earlier comments